# Flutter listview if i had a null value in my dataabase it show invalid arguement

Tags: mysql, flutter

has a value[image: null value] Hi Good Day my goal here is to display if have a null value and with a value in my listview because if my value in my database is null i had an error of invalid arguement.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: getData,
      key: _refresh,
      child: loading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                final x = list[i];
                debugPrint(x.toString());
                return ExpansionTile(
                  title: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                          'Transaction ID:\t' +
                              x.transaction_id +
                              '\nVesselname:\t' +
                              x.vesselname +
                              '\nVoyage #:\t' +
                              x.voyageno,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  children: <Widget>[
```

this are the values i want to display with a value or a null value

i try this ${x.anchor_eta } but it displays a null value i want to display empty or it has a value it will display date and time my data in my database is timestamp

```
title: Text(
                            'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + x.anchor_eta,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))),
                  
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: 'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n  ${x.anchor_eta }' i tried this one but it display the null in my listview i just want to display it into empty or like 00-00-0000 00:00

Answer (score 0):

Is the `anchor_eta` null ?

if yes you can do

```
(x.anchor_eta == null) ? '00-00-0000 00:00' : x.anchor_eta
```

so it will become like this

```
Text('Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + (x.anchor_eta == null) ? '00-00-0000 00:00' : x.anchor_eta
, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
```

Comment: 'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n ${x.anchor_eta }' i tried this one but it display the null in my listview i just want to display it into empty or like 00-00-0000 00:00

Comment: ill check this sir

Comment: it must a static type bool

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for printing empty space insted of 'null'

```
Text('Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + x?.anchor_eta ?? '', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
```

Comment: i have an invalid arguement

Comment: Can you please attach full log ?

Comment: Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(some_value==null){
 dateString = "No Dates";
} else {
 dateString = //date as string
}
```

go on to display it

```
Text(dateString);
```

or in short

```
Text(some_value==null?"No dates":some_value.toString()");
```

Comment: ill this one sorry sir i am a newbie in flutter

Comment: how to apply this sir?

Comment: you have to give us more details, post the whole error

Comment: title: Text(
                            'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + x.anchor_eta,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))), if i use this code and have a null value in my database i will have an error invalid arguement cause my value in my database is NULL